# Invoking a java SOAP Web Serivce from a Java Web Service with a private SSL Certificate on IBM Websphere

Tags: java, web-services, ssl, soap, client

So here is the scenario: Client A, Server B, Server C

A invokes a Web Service on Server B. After some logic in Server B in some cases he invokes Server C. C should give a Response to B and B to the Client A. So my server B is also a client from Server C.

The communication between B & C is with a private ssl certificate, which i configured in Websphere.

So here is the requst on server B which should invoke a WS on C

```
SoccerApi service = new SoccerApi();
SoccerApiPortType port = service.getSoccerApiSoccerApiSoapHttp();
port.someMethod(<Holder>paramater1, parameter2);
```

My Holder parameter is an INOUT Parameter, so i will get the response there.

Its not working, i dont get any any answer. The request is not working.

I know its very abstract but maybe u can tell some basics.

Thank you!